# Hadoop Configuration

Tags: hadoop

I have started configuring Hadoop 2.1.0-beta version for single node. I followed steps mentioned in Michael Noll's Tutorial (http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-multi-node-cluster/#configuring-single-node-clusters-first). Every thing I did and configured well. As a result of JPS, I got that NameNode, DataNode, Secondary NameNode started fine. Then I found out that there is no start-mapred.sh script. So I tried starting the jobtracker using hadoop-daemons.sh (hadoop-daemon.sh --config /home/nayan/dev/hadoop/etc/hadoop/ start jobtracker) and it resulted in failure with message "Sorry, the jobtracker command is no longer supported. You may find similar functionality with the "yarn" shell command.". I do not know what all configuration changes (if any) I need to make. I made changes in "yarn-site.xml" file, as suggested in Hadoop:The Definitive Guide. But could not proceed further. Where can I find out about Yarn. I checked Apache site, but could not figure it out.

Comment: What is your question?  You can find out about YARN here: http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/YARN.html

Comment: I wanted to ask that how can I start jobtracker and tasktracer in hadoop 2.1, if those commands are not available, neither start-mapred.sh.

Comment: I configured it by following directions from Hadoop : The Definitive Guide. Now I see every component running. But when I try to create a directory I always get directory not found for the path specified on the command prompt.

Comment: "hdfs dfs -mkdir /usr/hadoop/sample", I am getting error "mkdir: `/home/nayan/dev/hadoop/sample': No such file or directory". But when I tried to the same with "/tmp/hdfs/sample", directories got created. Can that be related to some user rights? Both locations have same set of privileges.

Comment: Then I tried to copy files from local system to hdfs directory "hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal hdfs-samples/*.* /tmp/hdfs/sample/".Error:13/08/30 17:28:29 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
copyFromLocal: unexpected URISyntaxException There were 8 files in local system, 7 got imported. "hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal hdfs-samples/example.pdf /tmp/hdfs/sample/"
It got imported without any issues. I tried the same thing with multiple directories.Everytime any one file is left out.I am not sure why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check your configuration xml files. Sometimes if you have any problrm in xml then some daemons wont start.
and try to use ./start-all.sh and then JPS

Answer (score 0):

you can use start-yarn.sh to start the ResourceManger and Jobtracker daemons

Answer (score 0):

I usually start everything using these two commands

```
./start-dfs.sh
./start-yarn.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

You Should use start-dfs.sh for Hdfs Daemons and start-yarn.sh for Resource manager and nodemanager daemon both are in /bin of hadoop.

Answer (score 0):

**./start-dfs.sh** or start-dfs.sh will start only HDFS components , while **./start-yarn.sh** or start-yarn.sh will start Yarn component like NodeManager , Resource manager etc. If you don't want to start both the components separately , try using this command :

**./start-all.sh** or start-all.sh (This is deprecated command though).

To answer your question , use **./start-yarn.sh**

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

First have to start the yarn daemons in the YARN( HADOOP 2.x) Environment.

So start with this 
at /hadoop_installed_path/sbin$ ./start-yarn.sh

Once the yarn daemons started then we can start df daemons 
at /hadoop_installed_path/sbin$ ./start-dfs.sh

Answer (score 0):

1.You should check all the steps in Hadoop The definitive guide.

if it's all proper than use start-all.sh
than run jps.

2.some time You have to close console for reflecting your changes.so close the console and reopen it again and then try jps,

hope this will help.